# What is the angle at critical point $z=1$ of $\left|z-\frac{i-1}{2}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}}$ under the Joukowski transform?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:**

> What is the angle at the critical point $z=1$ of the image of the circle $|z-\frac{i-1}{2}|=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}}$ under the Joukowski transform? The Joukowski transform is defined $J(z) = \frac{1}{2}(z+1/z)$.

Can someone provide an answer so I can verify and critique my attempt below?

**Attempt:**

We evaluate the tangent line of the circle that is orthogonal to the ray
$$ 1 - \frac{i-1}{2}.$$
Multiplication by $i$ yields
$$ (1 - \frac{i-1}{2}) \cdot i = \frac{3i}{2} + \frac{1}{2}. $$
The angle of inclination $\theta$ is then given by
$$ \tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{1}$$
$$ \theta = \arctan(3).$$
Since $z$ is a critical point of $J(z)$ and the lowest $m$ such that $f^{(m)}(z) \neq 0$ is $m=2$, it follows that the angle $\theta$ maps to $2\theta$. Hence, the angle at the critical point is $2\arctan(3)$.